# How to compose trait operations in Rust without knowing the exact type

Tags: generics, rust, types, traits

I'm creating a simple trait for natural numbers `Nat` with one implementation for `u64`. When I use this trait and use one operation with a type annotation, it figures out what implementation to use. However, when I specify a type for a composite expression, Rust is unable to compile the expression.

```rust
pub trait Nat {
    fn one() -> Self;
    fn succ(self) -> Self;
}

impl Nat for u64 {
    fn one() -> Self { 1 }
    fn succ(self) -> Self { return self + 1; }
}

#[test]
fn test_adder() {
    // Works well
    assert_eq!(4, 3.succ());
    let just_1: u64 = Nat::one();
    assert_eq!(just_1, 1);

    // Doesn't work
    let just_2: u64 = Nat::one().succ();
}
```

Comment: I guess the compiler just doesn't "look ahead" enough to get the information (possibly for performance reasons). If you just use `u64::one().succ()` it'll work fine because it gets the information upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a fully qualified call specifiying the type:

```rust
let just_2: u64 = <u64 as Nat>::one().succ();
```

or just use the type itself and let the compiler infer the trait method:

```rust
let just_2: u64 = u64::one().succ();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac805f69783aac92739bf02a41c1d4c8)

Comment: It's clear this would work but I was looking for a way to compose an expression using `one().succ()` and then cast it to a type rather than using concrete types from the start which limits reinterpretation.